# Railo not showing "List of existing gateway instances on Railo"

Tags: administration, railo

I am working on a railo site.I need to add a new gateway instance on Railo Web Administrator.I filled up the form for creating the new gateway instance and when submitted its not showing up under the "List of existing gateway instances".

I am using railo-4.2.1.008 version.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your root directory and application.cfc try deleting the application.cfc and create again.See If this works.

Comment: Thanks dude.you were right.I had an issue with the application.cfc ,which was causing this problem.